# Controlled input component in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any way how to control value of input only by on change handler in angular 4?

I would like to achieve the same behaviour as with React's [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

My final use case is to keep input state outside of the component in the store which emits state changes.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this: validators, custom directive or event handling for example

Comment: My use case is not validation, I want to have input state stored outside of the component

Comment: `<input maxlength="3"/>` ?

Comment: @JBNizet my use case is not validation. I want to keep and control input state from outside of the component

Comment: I have no idea of what you mean by that. Explain, as if I was a 5 year old boy, what should happen whenyou type 1, then 2, then 3, then 4 into the input. maxlength doesn't validate: it literally prevents you from entering more than 3 characters into the field, which is just what you asked, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @JBNizet maybe the example is a little bit misleading. I want to achieve the same behaviour as with React's `controlled components`

Comment: A 5 year old boy can't understand that.

Comment: @JBNizet you are not 5 years old, you can read, please follow the link in the question. I've also removed example since it was a bit misleading

Answer (score 1):

One way is to not used ngForms at all and use input field directly:

```
<input type="text" [value]="value" (keydown)="onChange($event)" />
```

and then in your component

```
  onChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = e.key;
  }
```

in this way you have full control - but it is rather low level - you must build your value always manually key by key.

Comment: This solution is almost it. As mentioned it is a low level, you have to handle backspace, shift, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you can do is the following:

First, in yout template

```
<input
  type="text"
  [ngModel]="value"
  (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)"
/>
```

Second, in your component

```
onValueChange(newValue: string) {
  this.value = newValue.toUpperCase()
}
```

*[reference: [v13](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties), [v9](https://v9.angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties), [v4](https://v4.angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#update)]*

that way you can control what your input stores in memory, in this case saving the string as uppercase.

Also keep in mind that this might not be the most propper way of doing things in  angular, I believe the optimal way is to use `FormControl` and `FormGroup`, if your are using those, you can obtain a reference of the FormControl in your component and use the

- `formControl.valueChanges` observable to observe the changes
- `formControl.setValue` function to update the inner state of the `FormControl`

I know this answer probably comes a bit late, but for all of those like me who are coming to angular from react, hope this helps you!

PS: I'm not too proficient in angular, so if there is a better way of doing things, I'm open to suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use maxlength attribute of an input element

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="value" maxlength="3">
```